# Beacon heading calucation

Tags: ibeacon, beacon, indoor-positioning-system

I am planning to create the indoor navigation system. It will provide the shortest path to user from source to destination.

Suppose I know all beacons location.
Is that possible to calculate user facing direction by a set of beacons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this is not possible.

**Off the shelf beacons are omnidirectional transmitters and mobile phones are omnidirectional receivers.  There is no way to determine directionality of the signal.**

The good news is that phones have two other ways of getting heading information -- the compass and a velocity vector.   The compass is the general approach if you are standing still.  If you are in motion, just calculate a vector between the last known location and the current location to get the heading.